# CMake, choose Xcode compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction, cmake

I know that until recently it was not possible to select any specific compiler for xcode projects generated by CMake (it would always choose xcodes default compiler). Anyways this post: http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/CMake-2-8-1-available-for-download-td4752230.html
makes me believe that it should be possible with a specific **CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_** flag by now.- Unfortunatelly I could neither find which flag is supposed to change xcodes compiler, nor a list of all xcode flags supported by CMake.

I am using Xcode 4.2 and CMake 2.8.6, and I'd like to be able to switch between LLVM 3.0 and LLVM GCC 4.2 from within CMake.

As I said a list, which lists all xcode flags I can change from within CMake would be great!

Thanks

**EDIT:**

with Cmake 2.8.6, if you want to generate an xcode project that does not default to Clang/LLVM 3.0, use the following:

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_VERSION "com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that CMake just transparently sets whatever attribute you set in the XCode Project file - so it supports any and all attributes that you like.

By inspection of one of my XCode project files, the attribute that you want seems to be `GCC_VERSION`, and these are the acceptable values (my XCode is 4.0.2, gcc v4.2).

```
GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0;
GCC_VERSION = 4.2
GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
```

<s>My CMake documentation seems to suggest that you want to set `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_X` not CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_X, too.</s>

Comment: thanks, that looks really promising, I will try that in a bit!

Comment: great, this works, but only with the CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE prefix, i.e. CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_VERSION. ty!